# Relationships using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using Eloquent in Laravel 5 and am a bit confused in relations between tables. These are existing tables of a software and cannot be altered.

I have the following tables that shows historical details of a student. All tables have model classes created.

```
student
-------
student_id (PK)
first_name
last_name

class
-----
class_id (PK)
name
section
year    //2012, 2013 etc
student_id (FK)

result
------
result_id (PK)
class_id (FK)
month       // jan, feb etc
status      //pass or fail
```

Below are the details of each table

- Student studies in a class for a particular year
- Each class for that year will have 10 results (1 result for each month in an year)
- Each result will contain the state for a test in a month (pass or fail)

I want to access objects based on the below examples. Can you guide on setting up relations in the model classes

```
student->class(2013)->result(jan)
result(feb)->class(2016)->student
```

Comment: Check the laravel documentation and laravel podcasts. There's a lot of good information there e.g. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should define the relationships between your models:

*Result.php model*

```
public function class(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Class::class');
}
```

*Class.php model*

```
public function results(){
    return $this->hasMany('Result::class');
}

public function student(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Student::class');
}
```

*Student.php model*

```
public function classes(){
    return $this->hasMany('Class::class');
}
```

Then, you can use some queries. For your first example `student->class(2013)->result(jan)`:

```
$results = Student::find($student_id)->classes()->where('year', '2013')->results()->where('month', 'jan')->get();
```

Also, if you will need to search classes by year and results by month a lot of times, you can easily add some methods like this in your models:

*Student.php model*

```
public function classesByYear($year){
    return $this->classes()->where('year', $year)->get();
}
```

*Class.php model*

```
public function resultsByMonth($month){
    return $this->results()->where('month', $month)->get();
}
```

So the previous example will become:

```
$results = Student::find($student_id)->classesByYear('2013')->resultsByMonth('jan');
```

---

EDIT: Your tables are using a custom identifier, so you must implement `protected $primaryKey = 'custom_id';` on each model.