# Database | PHP | Laravel ERROR?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I want to display episode of every season. i used "echo" at first query and has displayed "[]".What is the problems ? Please help :D

> ErrorException in 0405298c171379ebd6bef291f52165f99119355b.php line
>   47: Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not
>   be converted to int (View:
>   C:\xamppp\htdocs\filmeseriale\resources\views\admin\seriale\show.blade.php)
>   QUERY

```
    $sezon_episod2 = sezon_serial::select()->where('nume_serial','=',$seriale->id)->get();

   $episoade = Episod::where('id_serial','=',$seriale->id)->where('id_sezon','=',$sezon_episod2)->get();
```

The Html- show view

```
        @foreach($sezon_episod as $sezon)
            <div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">

                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{ $sezon->numar_sezon }}">Sezon: {{ $sezon->id }}</a>


                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse{{ $sezon->numar_sezon }}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="list-group">

                            @if($sezon->id == $sezon_episod2)

                                @foreach($episoade as $episod)

                            <li class="list-group-item">

                                Episodul: {{ $episod->nume_episod }}


                            </li>

                            @endforeach
                                @endif

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first query returns a collection, and then your are using this collection like an integer. Try with `first()` instead of `get()`, this will return a single **sezon_serial** object, so you shouldn't get a collection anymore.

```
$sezon_episod2 = sezon_serial::select('id')->where('nume_serial','=',$seriale->id)->first();
```

Comment: Thank you- the next error after editing Object of class App\sezon_serial could not be converted to int (View: C:\xamppp\htdocs\filmeseriale\resources\views\admin\seriale\show.blade.php)

Comment: @AdrianCaragea In which line? Probably here: `@if($sezon->id == $sezon_episod2)`. You are comparing an integer with an object. Try `@if($sezon->id == $sezon_episod2->id)`

Answer (score 1):

I solved but i need all, not only first.

```
$sezon_episod3 = sezon_serial::select()->where('nume_serial','=',$seriale->id)->first();

         $episoade = Episod::where('id_serial','=',$seriale->id)->where('id_sezon','=', $sezon_episod3->id)->get();
```

Show View

```
>  @if($sezon->id == $sezon_episod3->id)
>                                     @foreach($episoade as $episod)
>                                          <li class="list-group-item">
>                                              Episodul: {{ $episod->nume_episod }}
>                                         </li>
>                                     @endforeach
>                                 @endif
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suppose that you have a serials table, sezons table and episodes table and you want to show all the sezons and the episodes of each seazon for a specified serial. You only have to define the relationships between the models, and then it can be something like `@foreach($serial->sezons as $sezon) $sezon->name @foreach($sezon->episodes as $episode) $episode->name @endforeach @endforeach`. Of course, you have to use your own methods and properties names.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144246/relationships-using-eloquent/38144862#38144862) if you aren't already acquainted with eloquent relationships, or directly at [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships).

Answer (score 0):

Two different errors.

FIRST

> ErrorException in 0405298c171379ebd6bef291f52165f99119355b.php line
>   49: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:
>   C:\xamppp\htdocs\filmeseriale\resources\views\admin\seriale\show.blade.php)

Query

```
$sezon_episod2 = sezon_serial::select('id')->where('nume_serial','=',$seriale->id)->first();

            $episoade = Episod::select()->where('id_serial','=',$seriale->id)->where('id_sezon','=',$sezon_episod2)->first();
```

SHOW BLADE

```
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        @if($sezon->id == $sezon_episod2->id)
                            @foreach($episoade as $episod)
                                 <li class="list-group-item">
                                     Episodul: {{ $episod->nume_episod }}
                                </li>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </ul>
```

And when i put "->get()" at "$episoade" i have this error,

> ErrorException in 0405298c171379ebd6bef291f52165f99119355b.php line
>   72:
>
> > Trying to get property of non-object (View:
> >     C:\xamppp\htdocs\filmeseriale\resources\views\admin\seriale\show.blade.php)

Comment: First error: With `first()` you only have a single object, not a collection, so you can't iterate over a foreach. Second error: You are trying to get a property from a variable who is not an object, maybe it is a collection, or a null object if the query can't find any match on the database.